# finding a JVM porting to linux-arm

Tags: java-me, embedded, iptv

I'm trying to port a JVM to my linux-arm based set-top-box, which can run a midlet, i.e. it should be based on the MIDP profile.
I've tried the phoneMe Feature, but failed. Is there any better porting solution? I need your HELP, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably take [JavaSE for embedded](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html) and combine it with [microemu](http://code.google.com/p/microemu/wiki/Maemo) to get a MIDP environment.

Also check out [Jalimo](https://evolvis.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/jalimo/index.php/Main_Page), it may provide an alternate.